# Notepad++ copy/paste part of each line with replace

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

I am wondering if we can do the following with notepad++. I have an exhaustive list of all countries in the word, this is small part of it:

```
Afghanistan : '',
Albania : '',
Algeria : '',
American Samoa : '',
Andorra : '',
Angola : '',
Anguilla : '',
Antigua and Barbuda  : '',
```

I need to inject each of those countries between the single quotes, like this:

```
Afghanistan : 'Afghanistan',
Albania : 'Albania',
Algeria : 'Algeria',
American Samoa : 'American Samoa',
Andorra : 'Andorra',
Angola : 'Angola',
Anguilla : 'Anguilla',
Antigua and Barbuda  : 'Antigua and Barbuda',
```

Is there anyway where we can parse each line and inject the each country as indicated above using some kind or regular expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?)\h+:\h+'`
- Replace with: `$0$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  (.+?)     : group 1, 1 or more any character not greedy
  \h+       : 1 or more horizontal spaces
  :         : literally  colon
  \h+       : 1 or more horizontal spaces
  '         : single quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0      : whole match
$1      : content of group 1 (ie the country name)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Afghanistan : 'Afghanistan',
Albania : 'Albania',
Algeria : 'Algeria',
American Samoa : 'American Samoa',
Andorra : 'Andorra',
Angola : 'Angola',
Anguilla : 'Anguilla',
Antigua and Barbuda  : 'Antigua and Barbuda',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in Notepad++ with Regex **Search & replace**.

1. Open file in Notepad++
2. Open Search -> Replace from main menu (or Ctrl+H)
3. In `Find what:` line type `^(.*?)\s:\s'',$`
4. In `Replace with:` line type `$1 : '$1',`
5. Check `Regular expression` radio in `Search Mode` panel
6. Click `Replace All` button.

Below you can see the result I got from your sample data.
[image]